# Public transport in Cologne / Bonn

Tags: public-transport, tips-and-tricks, cologne, bonn

I'm going to be traveling to Cologne in September, partially to visit Photokina and partially for fun. I noticed a quite extensive tram network in the area, stretching from Cologne to Bonn. Is there a ticket available for tourists to allow usage for a number of days?

If not, is there a system like the public transport cards in use in the Netherlands/London so that you can take any tram/bus, or do I need to buy single tickets for every trip?

I do see the carnaval tickets available right now, but I doubt those will still be available or valid in September. But something like that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [VRS Pocket Guide](http://www.kvb-koeln.de/german/tarif/eng.html?INCLUDEMODUL=dokumente_einzeln2.mod/inc.download.php&downDokument=1013) (PDF) has all the info you need in a very accessible format. I've copied the fare segment here:

[image]

The weekly ticket (which always starts on Monday!) can be very cost effective if your travel matches it.

To figure out which type of ticket you need (1-7) you can input your trip in this journey planner: http://auskunft.kvb-koeln.de/kvb/cgi?lang=UK

It will show the required ticket for each proposed route (e.g. "*Preisestuff **4***"). For example, travel within Cologne requires a **1b** ticket, travel between Cologne and Bonn requires a **4** ticket and travel between Cologne and Dusseldorf requires a **5** ticket.

Comment: Weekly tickets sound nice, but seeing how I'll arrive on a Thursday, not of much use to me. Guess I'll be getting a bunch of day tickets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can get day-passes (called "TagesTicket") if you know you need to take the trains regulary on that day. They cost 8.50 for 1 person or 12.90 for 5 persons in the area of cologne, for the other variants check out their site (https://www.vrsinfo.de/tickets/preisliste.html)

Comment: The english link might be more helpful: https://www.vrsinfo.de/englisch/tickets-and-tariffs/short-term-tickets/single-ticket.html for transport within Cologne you need the 1b fare, click through the menu on the left to see the different options, including an explanation of the fare system.

Comment: English or German doesn't matter much to me personally, but it might be better for the rest of the site :) The day passes / TagesTickets sound great, thanks.